# NSFetchedResultsController sections name - Tracking EFFICIENCY

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is my core data structure

Entity - **Category**

Attr - **Id**(NSString) ***primary key***, **name**(NSString)

Entity - **Product**

Attr - **Id**(NSString), **name**(NSString), **parentCategoryId**(NSString) ***foreign key***,....

As can be seen from above, *Id from Category* points to *parentCategoryId from Product*.

In this case, I want to use *name from category* associated with concerned *parentCatrgoryId from product* as my section name for UITableView.(I use @"parentCategoryId" as key to NSSortDescriptors in fetchrequest)
But *parentCatrgoryId* are simply alphanumeric texts.

How can I decode the the alphanumeric text i.e. *parentCatrgoryId from product* to *name from category*

**EDIT**

***This is what I did & its working. But what I want to ask if what I did is efficient.***

I added one more attribute named **parentCategoryIdName** & used this to store the exact name by computing some simple operation.

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categoryArr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *productArr;
```

.m file

```
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.MOContext];
    // Setup the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    //    [request setPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates]];

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.MOContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [self setCategoryArr: mutableFetchResults];

    NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.MOContext];
    // Setup the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request2 setEntity:entity2];
    //    [request2 setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@""]];
    NSError *error2;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults2 = [[self.MOContext executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2] mutableCopy];
    [self setProductArr: mutableFetchResults2];
```

To insert the data in DB

```
    for (int i=0; i< [self.productArr count]; i++) {
        Product *productEnt = [self.productArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.MOContext;

            for (int j=0; j<self.categoryArr.count; j++) {
                Category *categroy = [self.categoryArr objectAtIndex:j];
                if ([categroy.objectId isEqualToString:productEnt.parentCategoryId]) {
                    [productEnt setParentCategoryIdName:categroy.name];
                }

            // Save the context.
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you plz post your fetch request code.

Comment: You may see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011363/section-names-from-nsfetchedresultscontroller-dont-match-the-managed-object-val

Comment: see my edited question. It includes the answer but I want to know what I did is efficient or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to recap:
From what I gather you need the id/name to form sections and show it in the section's title.

you solution would be efficient IMO but it should be the last resort:

ideas:
I would get the categoryName from categoryId JIT when you have to return the 
titleForSectionAtIndex:

OR if that is too slow.

fetch all section names when reloading the results.

=> Dont keep 'em in the database and duplicate data

**BUT**

if you *see* that it is really too slow, THEN denormalizing your data in that way is good IMO (it shoule be the last solution to consider)

Comment: I understood little what u said. So according to u answer in my edited question is not efficient. right?

Comment: I said: it is efficient but it is not nice and should be the last resort only

Comment: ok got it. my section is customized using `viewForHeaderInSection`. In this getting the categoryName from categoryId while returning the UIView seems very slow to me, as this methos gets called the times u scroll the table